# Why does MatchQ[a, r_ /; Head[r] != Plus] evaluate to False?

Tags: pattern-matching, head

I'm trying to understand. Why is it that:

```
MatchQ[a, r_ /; Head[r] != Plus]
```

Evaluates to:

```
False
```

? For me, I would think that, because:

```
Head[a]
```

Evaluates to:

```
Symbol
```

Where `a` has no value or expression assigned to it, then this:

```
MatchQ[a, r_ /; Head[r] != Plus]
```

Should evaluate to `True`. Could someone point me in the right direction to understanding this better? Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is this:

If `a` is a symbol then its `Head` is `Symbol`, so `Head[a] != Plus` reduces to `Symbol != Plus`. `Unequal` (`!=`) is supposed to be a mathematical test for inequality. In this case, it just cannot decide whether `Symbol != Plus` should evaluate to `True` or to `False`, since both sides are `Symbol`s. Here an example why this is undecidable with the current amount of information:

```
With[{Symbol = 1, Plus = 1}, Symbol != Plus]
With[{Symbol = 1, Plus = 0}, Symbol != Plus]
```

> False
>
> True

So the expression `Symbol != Plus` stays unevaluated. (This is the best strategy since later definitions could make it decidable.)

Because the second argument of `Condition` (`/;`) does not evaluate to `True`, the pattern does not match.

Lesson to learn: For testing for structual inequality, use `UnsameQ` (`=!=`):

```
MatchQ[a, r_ /; Head[r] =!= Plus]
```

> True

Of course, the same applies, mutatis mutandis, to `Equal` and `SameQ`.